# Operand of '*' must be a pointer error in c

Tags: c, struct, malloc, nodes

I am trying to work on an assignment with Struct nodes and linked lists. Here is a small part of the code where I am getting an error that I am unable to resolve. Please help Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct term{
    char term[200];
    double value;
};

void main(){
    struct term **terms = (struct term *)malloc(sizeof(struct term)); 
    // Using **terms is mandatory for the project
    *terms[0]->term = "abc";
    *terms[0]->value = 1; //This is line 15
    //I am unable to fix the error in line 15 at "*terms". 
    //The error message states "Struct term **terms: Operend of '*' must be a pointer"
    //The goal is to create nodes that can be accessed using *terms[i] with a for loop of index i
}
```

Comment: "terms" is a **, and you're dereferencing it three times: once with *, once with [], and once with ->. You probably mean something like "terms[0]->term".

Comment: We often do answer quickly, but we do not work to your schedule, so we do not usually take kindly to requests for quick response.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The variable "terms" is a ** (pointer to pointer), but you're dereferencing it three times: once with *, once with [], and once with ->. You probably mean "terms[0]->term".

Comment: The 2nd sentence is ok, the first is not. `*` doesn't dereference `terms` or direct expression thereof, but the `term` or `value` member

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this implementation. First of all, you are creating a double pointer so you also need to allocate memory for the inner-pointer you are pointing to.

```
struct term** terms = (struct term**)malloc(sizeof(struct term*));

*terms = (struct term*)malloc(sizeof(struct term));
```

Secondly, you cannot do an implementation like shown below.

```
char c[5];
void main(void)
{
    c = "abc";
}
```

This is wrong and compiler will throw an error. What you can do is to assign each character to the char array one-by-one. Alternatively you can use `strcpy` too.

```
((*terms)->term)[0] = 'a';
((*terms)->term)[1] = 'b';
((*terms)->term)[2] = 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this ...

> ```
>     struct term **terms = (struct term *)malloc(sizeof(struct term));
> ```

... `terms` represents an object of type `struct term **`, a pointer to a pointer to a `struct term`.  In that case,

- `*terms[0]->term` is equivalent to `*((terms[0])->term)` by operator precedence
- `terms[0]` is equivalent to `*terms`.  It is a pointer of type `struct term *`.
- `terms[0]->term` designates the member `term` of the structure to which `terms[0]` points, which is an array.  This array value is automatically converted to a pointer to the first array element for the purposes of evaluating the larger expression.
- `*terms[0]->term` therefore represents the first character in the array `terms[0]->term`.  It is equivalent to `terms[0]->term[0]`.  It does not make sense to attempt to assign a string literal to this one character.

Similarly, `terms[0]->value` designates member `value` of the structure to which `terms[0]` points.  *This is not a pointer*, so it is not a suitable operand for the `*` operator.  This is what your compiler's error message is telling you.

Syntactically, any of these would be consistent with the type of `terms`:

- `terms[0]->value = 1;`
- `(*terms[0]).value = 1;`
- `(*terms)->value = 1;`

HOWEVER, even if one of those were used, the code would still be badly broken.  I already mentioned the bad assignment to `*terms[0].term`. Also, the `malloc()` call reserves the wrong amount of memory for `terms` to point to, albeit probably more than enough for a single `struct term *`. Most problematically, however, `terms[0]` itself, the pointer, is never initialized with a valid (pointer) value.  It doesn't point to anything to whose members you could actually assign.  Probably, then, you want something more like this:

```
    struct term **terms = malloc(sizeof(*terms)); // enough space for one pointer
    *terms = malloc(sizeof **terms));             // enough space for one struct term

    strcpy(terms[0]->term, "abc");
    terms[0]->value = 1;
    // ...
```

Plus, the return type of `main()` must be `int`, not `void`.